# Powerbuilder label datawindow - Cutting the field value on left and right side

Tags: label, powerbuilder, datawindow

I have created a Label datawindow (all fields aligned to center). The field value(length = 80) is having no spaces in between. So while generating a label report from powerbuilder application the field is cutting left and right side.
[image]

In case the field has spaces in between, in the report it will go to next line.

Im using Powerbuilder 2017 R3.

If any advice it would be grateful
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please also add a screenshot?

Comment: Added Screenshot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to expand the display area of the columns to handle the max width.  If this isn't an option then you will have to programmatically break up the strings which have no spaces since PB doesn't know when to wrap since there are no breaks in the text.